# Вопрос про индексы в MySQL

Tags: индексы, mysql

Например есть MySQL запрос в файле **get.php**:

```
SELECT `id`, `uid` FROM `tasks` WHERE `uid` = 2 AND `read` = 0;
```

и есть запрос в файле **test.php**:

```
SELECT `id`, `uid` FROM `tasks` WHERE `uid` = 2;
```

Какой индекс ставить в таком случае? Составной на uid и read? Или по отдельности на uid и read?

Comment: @ModaL, перечитайте свои прошлые вопросы и ответы на них. по ходу по второму кругу пошло.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет.
Индексы ставить вообще необязательно, а делается это для увеличения производительности.
Индекс строит дерево поиска, после чего быстро быстро работают *SELECT* вроде вашего (в идеальном случае за O(log(n)), где n - количество записей)

Однако *INSERT* работают дольше, т.к. приходится пересчитывать индекс.

Индекс нужен такой как условие, если условие по двум полям то и индекс по двум, если есть по каждому отдельно, то по двум не нужен.

Comment: если read = 0 почти для всех записей, то составной индекс не нужен, достаточно индекса по uid.